# Vacuum Tube Computer Logic

Tags: architecture

In StackExchange ElectricalEngineering there is the question:

Were Vacuum Tube Computers made of Logic Gates?

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/704329/were-vacuum-tube-computers-made-of-logic-gates

Is StackExchange - Retrocomputing the more appropriate area?

Note: I have no idea if or when it is appropriate to move a question. How to move a question if that is even possible. Or how you are can inform people in one forum about a topic of interest in another forum.

Don't worry, I'll delete this question in 24 hours. It really comes down to how do you inform people of an interesting question in another forum.

Comment: Not really a great question - at least as worded - as based on a misconception of gates being something other than abstraction level. And the only two mostly good answers are in MHO Kuba's and yours. When it comes to tube computers it's important to remember that tubes are there primary for one issue: providing a NOT (well, and amplifying again :)) NOT is the only function that needs an active component. Same as with relay based computers.

Comment: check out https://www.youtube.com/@UsagiElectric, he's building a 1bit computer from vacuum tubes, and restoring a bendix G15 machine from somewhen in the 1960s that also used them

Comment: Please do not delete this question in 24 hours, it is a good question to have around. But it definitely belongs on the meta site and not on the main site.